# Julia function for weighted variance returning "wrong" value

Tags: julia, variance

I'm trying to calculate the weighted variance using Julia, but when I compare the results
with my own formula, I get a different value.

```
x = rand(10)
w = Weights(rand(10))
Statistics.var(x,w,corrected=false) #Julia's default function
sum(w.*(x.-mean(x)).^2)/sum(w)      #my own formula
```

When I read the docs for the "var" function, it says that the formula for "corrected=false" is
the one I wrote.

Comment: Can you provide the formula from the documentation that you are duplicating?

Comment: He is talking about https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/scalarstats/#Statistics.var I assume

Comment: The formula is the one in the link from @crstnbr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to subtract a weighted mean in your formula to get the same result:

```
sum(w.*(x.-mean(x,w)).^2)/sum(w)
```

or (to expand it)

```
sum(w.*(x.- sum(w.*x)/sum(w)).^2)/sum(w)
```

Comment: I have edited my answer (I copy-pasted wrong code in one place). Now it is correct. Sorry for this.